# django retrieving objects, empty values

Tags: json, django, django-models

I use `Profile.objects.values('id', 'avatar')` to retrieve objects from a table, but I want when value of `avatar` is empty to be set with `media/profile.png`, my model

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True, default='media/profile.png')
```

and return everything in json with `JsonResponse(data, safe=False)`

```
[{"id": "1", "avatar": ""}, {"id": "2", "avatar": ""}, {"id": "3", "avatar": "media/profile.png"}, {"id": "4", "avatar": "media/art_xpr.png"}]
```

and is used in javascript frontend, but the problem is that the avatar is empty in some cases .

Comment: Please do *not* use `.values` to construct a JSON response, use what is dedicated for this task: a *serializer*.

Comment: so either you write a script to add the missing values in your db or you set the default value in the frontend via js. No need to validate this in the backend before sending it to the front end since in this case you have a clear default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a better way but this also will work

```
Profile.objects.annotate(
    avatar_or_default=Case(
        When(avatar='', then=Value('media/profile.png')), 
        default=F('avatar'), 
        output_field=CharField()
    )).values('id', 'avatar_or_default')
```

Output should be something like this

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'avatar_or_default': 'media/custom.png'}, {'id': 2, 'avatar_or_default': 'media/profile.png'}, {'id': 3, 'avatar_or_default': 'media/profile.png'}]>
```